# How to solve TPTP Monitor error ( IWAT0435E ) in Eclipse, on Debian-based Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, eclipse-tptp

After installing Test & Performance Tools Platform in Eclipse Ganymede on, whenever I tried to profile a Java application, I was confronted by the launch configuration dialogue which contained an error along the lines of:

```
Error IWAT0435E could not connect to host
```

How is this problem fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching for a while I found the solution in a couple of blogs, so thanks to 
[Pablo](http://goodenoughjava.blogspot.com/2008/10/profiling-with-eclipse-tptp-problem.html) and [Shimi](http://myjavanotebook.blogspot.com/2008/04/libstdc210-glibc22-on-ubuntu-hardy-804.html). These contain a more detailed background if you're interested.

The problem related to something called the Agent Controller being linked to an old version of libstdc++. To solve it you can run the following two commands:

```
wget mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-2.95/libstdc++2.10-glibc2.2_2.95.4-24_i386.deb
sudo dpkg --install libstdc++2.10-glibc2.2_2.95.4-24_i386.deb
```

Though your mileage may vary depending on distro version etc.

You should then be able to profile successfully in Eclipse, I found that I didn't even need to restart Eclipse.

Comment: 2010 and still using i386 libs?

Answer (score 3):

Use the following if you're using Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic Koala 64 bit

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-3.3/libstdc++5_3.3.6-17ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libstdc++5_3.3.6-17ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Launch eclipse and viola...you're in business :)

Comment: Worked fine even on Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx 64-bit with TPTP-4.6.2 on Eclipse from repositories.

Answer (score 2):

Just install the 'libstdc++5' package from the repos.  No need to bother with manually fetching the deb file. (I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 64bit)

e.g. type the following in a terminal:

> sudo apt-get install libstdc++5

Answer (score 0):

Problem: you need to have libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3 installed.
To solve this problem on openSUSE install package "compat".